# Better way to find array element index?

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, architecture, grid

I am relatively new to Swift and programming in general.

I'm working on a project with a two dimensional array to represent a grid in which I'm storing custom objects:

```
class Grid {
    var element: [[GridElement]]
}
```

I frequently need to access the elements by its coordinates. Ex:

```
let gridElement = grid.element[coord.x][coord.y]
```

**But** I also need to frequently get the coordinates back from a given gridElement (its indices in the 2d array). This results in a nested loop that doesn't seem to be the fastest or most elegant solution:

```
func getCoord(_ gridElement: GridElement) -> Coord {
    for x in 0..<xSize {
        for y in 0..<ySize {
            if element[x][y] == gridElement { return Coord(x: x, y: y) }
        }
    }
    return Coord(x: -1, y: -1)
}
```

As I want this to work smoothly with large grids, this doesn't look like a solution. Am I missing something simple?

**I am considering storing the coordinate in the GridElement object itself**, but this also feels like bad design because I would need to constantly update it when the GridElement changes location.

This is more of a design/architecture question than it is looking for a magical function to solve my problems. It feels like the design pattern for a **two way reference** should be established but I have not been able to turn up an answer. Any advice?

Comment: How is `GridElement` defined? How is `element` filled, Does every subarray of `element` contain elements with the same `x` coordinate? And when calling `grid.element[coord.x][coord.y]` are you sure that there won't be an `Index out of range` error?

Answer (score 0):

> I am considering storing the coordinate in the GridElement object itself, but this also feels like bad design because I would need to constantly update it when the GridElement changes location.

I think something like this is a viable solution. Instead of storing it inside the grid element object, you can store the coordinates in another dictionary:

```
private var gridElementPositionDict: [GridElement: Coord]
```

As you said, this will require you to constantly set the values for `gridElementPositionDict` whenever a grid element changes position. **However, you can use some encapsulation so that you only set them in one place.**

First, make your `elements` array `private`, and add a `subscript` that takes two parameters to your `Grid` class. The subscript will accept a `Coord` for accessing a particular grid element at a particular position. In the setter of this subscript, you can modify the `gridElementPositionDict` to set the `GridElement`'s new positions.

Then, you can write another method (or subscript) that accepts a `GridPosition` that returns its position.

You can also add methods like `swapElements(at:and:)`, `changeElementPositon(_:to:)` etc. It's all about encapsulating your data structure.

Here's some code as an example:

```
class Grid<T: Hashable> {
    private var elements: [[T?]]
    private var elementsPositionDict: [T: Coord]

    init() {
        elements = [
            [nil, nil, nil, nil],
            [nil, nil, nil, nil],
            [nil, nil, nil, nil],
            [nil, nil, nil, nil],
        ]
        elementsPositionDict = [:]
    }

    subscript(_ coord: Coord) -> T? {
        get { return elements[coord.x][coord.y] }
        set {
            // this is the ONLY place you modify the dictionary
            if let oldValue = elements[coord.x][coord.y] {
                elementsPositionDict[oldValue] = nil
            }
            elements[coord.x][coord.y] = newValue
            if let v = newValue {
                elementsPositionDict[v] = coord
            }
        }
    }

    func coord(of element: T) -> Coord? {
        return elementsPositionDict[element]
    }
}
```

Comment: returning `elements[coord.x][coord.y]` is brave

Comment: @ielyamani What do you mean? Should I not have done that? I don't see anything wrong with that. `Array` crashes when you try to access an invalid index. Why can't `Grid` do the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `getCoord` function should be like:

```
func getCoord(_ gridElement: GridElement) -> Coord {
    for (i, row) in element.enumerated() {
        if let index = row.firstIndex(of: gridElement) {
            return Coord(x: i, y: index)
        }
    }
    return Coord(x: -1, y: -1)
}
```